# SQL Select statement loop on one column in different table

Tags: sql-server, select

Good day Guys, Would you help me with my SQL Query. I have on proj in the web which I called **INQUIRY** good thing is I can store the log file of what data is being search to my project which they enter to my inquiry search box.

This is the table of Keyword have been searched in INQUIRY:

[image]

This Code :

```
Insert into #temptable
    Select CaseNo from tblcrew 
    where Lastname like '%FABIANA%' 
    and firstname like '%MARLON%'

Insert into #temptable    
    Select CaseNo from tblcrew 
    where Lastname like '%DE JOAN%' 
    and firstname like '%ROLANDO%'

Insert into #temptable
    Select CaseNo from tblcrew 
    where Lastname like '%ROSAS%' 
    and firstname like '%FRANCASIO%'
```

I want to repeat my query until all the rows in table of keyword is being search and save the result of each query into a temporary table. Is there a possibility to do that without typing all the value of in the columns of keyword.

Please anyone help me.. thanks!

Comment: you did not explain at all the "loop"

Comment: Your question is not clear .

Answer (score 0):

All you need is join the two tables together without typing any values.

```
Insert into #temptable
Select c.CaseNo 
  from tblcrew c
 inner join tblKeyword k
    on c.Lastname like '%'+k.Lastname+'%'
   and c.firstname like '%'+k.firstname +'%'
```

Comment: But I have 100 rows in tblkeyword. Is there a chance that i will not type all 500 different values?

Comment: Look at the query - you don't need to type any values

Comment: The like will cause a sub-optimal plan to be generated.  Worst case is a index scan, best case is a index seek with extract Nested Loops, see analysis below.

Answer (score 0):

Usually start with the Adventure Works database for examples like this.  I will be talking about exact matches with leverage an index seek, in-exact matches that leverage a index scan, and full text indexing  in which you can do a in-exact match resulting in a seek.

The Person.Person table has both last and first name like your example.  I keep just the primary key on business id and create one index on (last, first).

```
--
-- Just PK & One index for test
-- 

-- Sample database
use [AdventureWorks2012];
go

-- add the index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Person_LastName_FirstName] ON [Person].[Person]
(
    [LastName] ASC,
    [FirstName] ASC
);
go
```

Run with wild card for inexact match.  Run with just text for exact match.  I randomly picked two names from the Person.Person table.

```
--
-- Run for match type
--

-- Sample database
use [AdventureWorks2012];
go

-- remove temp table 
drop table #inquiry;
go

-- A table with first, last name combos to search
create table #inquiry
(
first_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50)
);
go

-- Add two person.person names
insert into #inquiry values

('%Cristian%', '%Petculescu%'),
('%John%', '%Kane%');
/*
('Cristian', 'Petculescu'),
('John', 'Kane');
*/
go

-- Show search values
select * from #inquiry;
go
```

The next step when examining run times is to clear the procedure cache and memory buffers.  You do not want existing plans or data skew the numbers.

```
-- Remove clean buffers & clear plan cache
CHECKPOINT 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO

-- Show time & i/o
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO
```

The first SQL statement will do a inner join between the temporary search values table and Person.Person.

```
-- Exact match
select * 
from 
[Person].[Person] p join #inquiry i 
on p.FirstName = i.first_name and p.LastName = i.last_name
```

The statistics and run times.

*Table 'Person'. Scan count 2, logical reads 16, physical reads 8, CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 29 ms.*

The resulting query plan does a table scan of the #inquiry table and a index seek of the index on a  last and first name.  It is a nice simple plan.

[image]

Lets retry this with a inexact match using wild cards and the LIKE operator.

```
-- In-Exact match
select * 
from 
[Person].[Person] p join #inquiry i 
on p.FirstName like i.first_name and p.LastName like i.last_name
```

The statistics and run times.

*Table 'Person'. Scan count 2, logical reads 219, CPU time = 32 ms,  elapsed time = 58 ms.*

The resulting query plan is a-lot more complicated.  We are still doing a table scan of #inquiry since it does not have an index.  However, there are a-lot of nested joins going on to used the index with a impartial match.

We added three more operators to the query and the execution time is twice that of the exact match.

[image]

In short, if you are doing inexact matches with the LIKE command, they will be more expensive.

If you are searching hundreds of thousands of records, use a FULL TEXT INDEX (FTI).  I wrote two articles on this topic.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1421
http://craftydba.com/?p=1629

Every night, you will have to have a process that updates the FTI with any changes.  After that one hit, you can use the CONTAINS() operator to leverage the index in fuzzy matches.

I hope I explained the differences.  I have seen continued confusion on this topic and I wanted to put something out on Stack Overflow that I could reference.

Best of luck Juan.